# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/poll/public' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, token

I know it is a duplicate question but I can not fix it.
I used Angular for the front end and send this request:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/poll/public' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.FnbUC-WxRLG1IhyCNUfS1oojWFNIY_rl7kytqbefXlk' \
--header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
--header 'Referer: http://localhost:4200/' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
--data '{
    "start": 0,
    "length": 5
}'
```

The return value is:

[image: has been blocked by CORS policy]

The backend application was built using Java [spring boot]
and I do this in Application.java

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/api/v1/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200/**")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE").allowedHeaders("*").allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
}
```

Note: this request is working in Postman, and I send many requests but without tokens and it is working,
when I try to send a request from an angular app with header [authentication], the value of the header is null in the backend application.

Answer (score -1):

For CORS Configuration

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
}
```

For Token

```
private String validateToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String jwtToken = request.getHeader("Authorization").replace("Bearer", "");
        return jwtToken;
}
```